# openzeppelin dependencies pragma conflict

Tags: openzeppelin, version-pragma

I am working with the nice old pancakeswap "Lottery.sol" contract. I am trying to compile it but the lottery contract im working with is kinda old.
Hello there,

Open zeppelin contracts have been updated over time, which means their pragma version requirements are new too.

In order to avoid:

```
The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config
```

Would it be ok to find older versions of the openzeppelin dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I have found the answer myself:

You can install specific versions of OpenZeppelin Contracts using the version tag. You should only use an official release.